# How to reserve public IP Address for later use in Azure portal?

Tags: azure

I have created a Azure resource group. I want to add a public IP address to the resource group which I will use with a virtual machine later.

I tried adding the IP Address to a Network Interface from Azure Portal. It works but I want to know if there are alternative approaches. Also to note that currently I can not reserve range of IP address to my resource group, I also want to know how to achieve this.

Comment: Check this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/create-public-ip-portal?tabs=option-1-create-public-ip-standard if it's helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to create the Public IP using Azure "Public IP addresses" tab?
if not, locate the "Public UP addresses" under All services and then proceed to fill in all the necessary configuration.
[Azure Portal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzt5S.png)